# How can I use getSystemService in a non-activity class (LocationManager)?

Tags: android

I'm having trouble offloading tasks from the main Activities OnCreate method onto another class to do the heavy lifting.

When I try to call getSystemService from the non-Activity class an exception is thrown.

lmt.java:

```java
package com.atClass.lmt;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.location.Location;

public class lmt extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
        fyl lfyl = new fyl();
        Location location = lfyl.getLocation();
        String latLongString = lfyl.updateWithNewLocation(location);

        TextView myLocationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myLocationText);
        myLocationText.setText("Your current position is:\n" + latLongString);
    }
}
```

fyl.java

```java
    package com.atClass.lmt;
    
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.content.Context;
    
    public class fyl {
        public Location getLocation(){
            LocationManager locationManager;
            String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
            locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(context);
            
            String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            
            return location;
        }
    
        public String updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
            String latLongString;
            
            if (location != null){
                double lat = location.getLatitude();
                double lng = location.getLongitude();
                latLongString = "Lat:" + lat + "\nLong:" + lng;
            }else{
                latLongString = "No Location";
            }
            
            return latLongString;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Adding the exception and stack trace to the question may help potential answerers

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the mistake. The exception is thrown if I try to extend the Activity class with this one. I do not want to extend the Activity class for this class and simply want to be able to call getSystemService from within my getLocation method.    Exception:  java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

Answer (score 310, accepted):

You need to pass your context to your fyl class..
One solution is make a constructor like this for your `fyl` class:

```
public class fyl {
 Context mContext;
 public fyl(Context mContext) {
       this.mContext = mContext;
 }

 public Location getLocation() {
       --
       locationManager = (LocationManager)mContext.getSystemService(context);

       --
 }
}
```

So in your activity class create the object of fyl in `onCreate` function like this:

```
package com.atClass.lmt;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.location.Location;

public class lmt extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        fyl lfyl = new fyl(this); //Here the context is passing 

        Location location = lfyl.getLocation();
        String latLongString = lfyl.updateWithNewLocation(location);

        TextView myLocationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myLocationText);
        myLocationText.setText("Your current position is:\n" + latLongString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't get it, code would be more helpful. If anything I should be passing a LocationManager object to the getLocation method... I don't really see how me passing the context to the method will help when I cannot even call getSystemService without writing this class as an extended class to Activity.

Comment: did you tried this. In the onCreate if you are passing access the context by 'this'

Comment: but if the `lmt` class wont get executed then `fly` wont be having context

Comment: BTW `getSysytemService()`only accepts `String` as a parameter. Therefore you **cannot** pass a context to it. _How do I get around this?_ @Hunt

Comment: You don't need to pass context into that class. [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39065445/1074799)

Comment: Just to mention, Android managers (`BluetoothManager`, `ActivityManager` etc.) are also [constructed](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/742a67127366c376fdf188ff99ba30b27d3bf90c/core/java/android/app/ActivityManager.java#62) that way (not necessarily passing an `Activity` context to their constructor) and this is why they can access components in application scope.

Comment: Instead pass context to `getLocation` and make it static.  
`public static Location getLocation(Context context) { locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(context); }`

Comment: this is now outdated

Answer (score 54):

You can go for this :

```
getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Comment: getActivity() method is undefined for the class. This error shows up.

Comment: What is the class type in which you are using it?
i.e. it is a receiver class, fragment, simple java class or any other.

Comment: You need to extend your Activity with FreagmentActivity instead of an Activity. I hope it'll work for you...?

Comment: It doesn't work for a simple class where I want to extend `ArrayAdapter`.

Comment: Dear, what do you mean by a class.? Do you mean a fragment..? What is the problem you facing.

Comment: @MrAsterisco: 2017 This method works for me in fragment

Comment: Dear @MrAsterisco , It will work in any of the non-activity class, in fragment as well as in simple java classes too. In simple java classes, you just need to pass the Context reference(this) from the activity from which you are calling java class.
Feel free to ask if some clarification?

Comment: MIne worked by using getContext() instead of getActivity()!

Answer (score 17):

One way I have gotten around this is by create a static class for instances. I used it a lot in AS3 I has worked great for me in android development too.

**Config.java**

```
public final class Config {
    public static MyApp context = null;
}
```

**MyApp.java**

```
public class MyApp extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Config.context = this;
    }
    ...
}
```

You can then access the context or by using `Config.context`

```
LocationManager locationManager;
String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
locationManager = Config.context.getSystemService(context);
```

Comment: The problem I see with this method is it leaves something unprotected that, if someone were to assign null to it, would probably produce a catastrophic failure?

Comment: A variation on this is to put a private static in MyApp, and then add getters.  `private static MyApp _context;`   `public static MyApp getContext() {  return _context;  }` ... in onCreate:   `_context = this;`  in onStop: `_context = null;` ...   Usage:  `MyApp.getContext()`.

Comment: It maybe lead to memory leak

Comment: This will absolutely lead to memory leak. Ideally you should not use this process .

Answer (score 1):

For some non-activity classes, like [Worker](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Worker), you're already given a Context object in the public constructor.

```
Worker(Context context, WorkerParameters workerParams)
```

You can just use that, e.g., save it to a private Context variable in the class (say, `mContext`), and then, for example

```
mContext.getSystenService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this
in Activity:

```
private Context context = this;

........
if(Utils.isInternetAvailable(context){
Utils.showToast(context, "toast");
}
..........
```

in Utils:

```
public class Utils {

    public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but I did this:

```
LocationManager locationManager  = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: The right way is to use in a static way, as @Maddy says

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get it in a fragment this would work in kotlin:

```
requireActivity().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
```