# Downloading files from Web View Android app

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm trying to download files from my Web View Android app?
I'm newbie to android development. And I've no idea whats wrong with my code.

*

> Error:(31, 57) error: cannot find symbol method
>   getSystemService(String) Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

*

Here is my code:
MyAppWebViewClient.java

```
public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if (url.contains(".apk")) {
            Uri source = Uri.parse(url);
            // Make a new request pointing to the .apk url
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);
            // appears the same in Notification bar while downloading
            request.setDescription("Description for the DownloadManager Bar");
            request.setTitle("YourApp.apk");
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            }
            // save the file in the "Downloads" folder of SDCARD
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "SmartPigs.apk");
            // get download service and enqueue file
            DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            manager.enqueue(request);
            return true;
        }

        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().contains("mysite.com")) {
            return false;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: `getSystemService` in a method of `Context` class. If you want to use it in a non-activity class, refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4870714/4350275

Comment: The error suggests that there is something wrong with getSystemService() method. Can you try this.getSystemService()?

Answer (score 0):

getSystemService method will not work without context in Non-Activity Class. 
Try

> getContext().getSystemService()

Answer (score 0):

For Non-Activity classes as in your case `MyAppWebViewClient` if we want to access methods of Context class we have to do so using Context class instance. So the best way to do so is create a constructor and pass Context class instance in parameter.

```
public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
private final Context context;

public MyAppWebViewClient(Context context){
this.context = context;
}
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if (url.contains(".apk")) {
            Uri source = Uri.parse(url);
            // Make a new request pointing to the .apk url
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);
            // appears the same in Notification bar while downloading
            request.setDescription("Description for the DownloadManager Bar");
            request.setTitle("YourApp.apk");
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            }
            // save the file in the "Downloads" folder of SDCARD
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "SmartPigs.apk");
            // get download service and enqueue file
            DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            manager.enqueue(request);
            return true;
        }

        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().contains("mysite.com")) {
            return false;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Whenever you call `MyAppWebViewClient` class from activity class, just pass activity context when you create a new instance of the same class. Like

```
MyAppWebViewClient myAppWebViewClient = new MyAppWebViewClient(YourActivityName.this);
```

Hope this will help you.